# Problem installing leiningen on mac os

Tags: macos, clojure, installation, leiningen

I am trying to install Leiningen on mac os 10.6.4, following the instructions here - http://alexott.net/en/clojure/ClojureLein.html. The package is being downloaded, but lein command is not found. What could be the problem?

Comment: Make sure to open a new tab or `touch` your updated .bash_profile or .bashrc to make sure your $PATH has been updated after installing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to copy the executable in a directory which is in your path (/usr/local/bin/), for instance.

Type `echo $PATH` to see the different directories.

You'll also need to make the file executable:

```
chmod 555 /usr/local/bin/lein
```

Comment: I added the directory of the downloaded .jar file in $PATH. Is the .jar file what you mean by executable?

Comment: There's no JAR file, just a Shell script: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/raw/stable/bin/lein